# How to dissect/parse 'a two-horse policy of stimulating renting and owning'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

Foreword: Please beware that I already asked about my angst over ['albeit that' on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/233265).
[Source:](http://www.cih.org/resources/PDF/Policy%20free%20download%20pdfs/Policy%20essay%208%20-%20Putting%20home%20ownership%20in%20its%20place%20-%20June%202014.pdf) p 5 of 16, *Where is housing
heading?*,  by [Dr Peter Williams](http://www.cchpr.landecon.cam.ac.uk/directory/PeterWilliams). 2014 June

> What we have seen in recent years is a degree of caution by ministers in both pronouncements and policy
>   regarding homeownership, with the coalition clearly backing **a [two-horse](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/two-horse) policy** of ***stimulating renting and
>   owning*** albeit that, as housing moved higher up the political ladder, there has been a clear shift towards
>   `the latter`.

Does this excerpt truly reveal what is the specific **[two-horse](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/two-horse) policy** here? I'm confused because `the latter` seems to refer back to ***owning*** in ***stimulating renting and
owning*** ? But then this alleged reference implies that ***stimulating*** was [gapped as an ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gapping) => ***stimulating renting and [stimulating]
owning***. In other words, `the latter` truly means ***[stimulating]
owning***.

Per contra, this excerpt concerns homeownership by the general UK public. A layperson can only rent or own; so nothing here resembles a horse race? Was [two-horse](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/two-horse) used correctly and aptly here?

Comment: See also "hedging one's bets", "covering all bases", "straddling the fence", "talking out of both sides of one's mouth", "two-faced", "something for everyone", "stereotypical politician", "gatherers and sharers", "fair".

Comment: This would be spoken so: "backing a two-horse policy of stimulating renting *ánd* owning", rather than "renting 'n owning".  'Stimulating' has a dual object.

Answer (score 1):

'Backing a two-horse race' = betting on all possible outcomes.

As any gambler would know, that's no way to make money, as the bookie [turf accountant] will always want his profit margin.
So even though you 'win' whichever horse makes it past the post first, ultimately you are worse off.